# How do you block out multple of the same user in a browsergame?

Tags: web, browser, proxy, ip, vpn

I recently played a browser game public to everyone and noticed that some players used vpns or different browsers to join the same game multiple times which pretty much made the game unplayable.
I'm pretty new to website stuff but I still want to know if there was a way to prevent this.

Would banning a list of VPN IPs work against vpns? What about the different browsers?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You probably need to re-think the approach. It is relatively easy to have multiple browsers open and multiple connections to any public service, such as your game. It is also relatively difficult to block this kind of activity.

Perhaps it would help if you provided some detail around why this is an issue for you?

Comment: It is not really my issue I just wanted to know what ways there are to go about this...